# Why are homeomorphisms the isomorphisms of topological spaces?

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

I'm having trouble understanding why the statement in the question is true. My current understanding is as follows.

In category theory, an isomorphism between two objects $A$ and $B$ in the same category is defined as a map between them that has an inverse map.

A homeomorphism is defined as a continuous function between two topological spaces that has a continuous inverse.

Why are homeomorphisms exactly the isomorphisms of the topological space category, i.e. why can we not have discontinuous maps (given that we can probably find inverse maps, which would fit the bill for an isomorphism)?

There is a similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1669598/294784), but with a slightly broader scope.

Comment: Tiny nit, it's possible to define categories where the objects are topological spaces and yet the morphisms are something other than all continuous maps (whether more general or more narrow or completely different). In this context the notion of "isomorphism" could change. A category involves not only a specification of objects (here, "topological spaces") but a specification of what the morphisms are. There is no abstract reason why the morphisms would have to be functions on the underlying sets, although continuous functions on those sets this is a commonly understood default choice.

Comment: Combining Ittay's answer with your comment I now understand it like this: an isomorphism is actually a morphism that has an inverse morphism, and morphisms have to be specified for a category. As such, if morphisms are specified to be continuous for the category of topological spaces, isomorphisms must also be continuous. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. If the objects are topological spaces and the morphisms are the continuous maps (this category is sometimes denoted "Top" although the notation is not universal), then isomorphisms are continuous bijections with continuous inverses. In general, it really comes down to the definition of morphism. For example it is quite possible for two topological spaces to be homeomorphic in the topological sense but not isomorphic in some category where morphisms are required to have algebraic structure (e.g. because a polynomial mapping, even if bicontinuous, may not have a *polynomial* inverse).

Comment: Oh that's perfectly clear now, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definition of the category of topological spaces demands that the morphisms are the continuous functions between the underlying sets. So, for a morphism to be an isomorphism in that category it must itself be continuous and its inverse must be in the same category, namely must also be continuous.